# How to access attribute in jQuery callback func?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, class, object

```
var some_name =
{
    moving:false,

    show : function ()
    {
        this.moving = true;

        $('element').slideDown(5000, function ()
        {
            this.moving = false; //How to access to attribute "moving" of class some_name?
        });
    },
}
```

Question in code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind the callback function to the current context:

```
$('element').slideDown(5000, $.proxy(function() {
    this.moving = false;
}), this); // "this" inside of the function will be this "this"
```

See [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

---

Alternatively you could do this:

`this` is the current context, it's value depends on how the function is called. You can assign `this` to a variable outside of the function, and use this variable instead:

```
var that = this;
$('element').slideDown(5000, function() {
    that.moving = false; //use that instead of this here
});
```

Comment: The main problem with `$.proxy` in your example is that it's a function invocation *inside* an arguments list of another function invocation, so it's easy to miss the second right paren `)` - as you demonstrated yourself `:p`

Comment: If you don't need to access 'moving' from outside the object, just remove the this. before moving. It will work exactly the same way as you access your 'that'... This answer is the classical one, when you need to access 'this' from the callbacks. But it's overkill if you just need the access variables that you won't access from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Use `moving` instead of `this.moving` (in both occurences)

Variables are bound to the context when they are used, so even inside your event callback you can access the variables above.

Comment: this won't allow other methods of the object to access `moving`

Comment: Other methods *will* have access as long as moving is declared outside of a method. The only thing is that 'moving' will be a private variable. Your solution above works, but it's overkill in my opinion.

Comment: you would have to wrap the whole object + moving variable in a IIFE to make it private

Comment: Sure, sorry when I said "private" I meant without nice accessor a la ‘object.moving‘

Answer (score 0):

In the event callbacks, `this` refers to `event.target`, or the element that captured the event.

You can take the advantage of closures in javascript and access the `moving` attribute like this:

```
show : function ()
{
    var moving = true;

    $('element').slideDown(5000, function ()
    {
        moving = false;
    });
},
```

**Note**, though, that this `moving` will be different of the first `moving` that lives in `some_name`